# Call up - input type="text" according to the selected option

Tags: javascript, html, text

I would like to show 1 to 3 input ="text"  fields in the HTML area, depending on the option selected. 
(The options to be selected are loaded in a JSON file)
But I just can't do it... ;-( Hope one of you can help me out.

This is the last part of the Javascript:

```
        $(document).on('change', '#kunde', function () {
            var kunde_id = $(this).val();
            if (kunde_id != '')
             {
                load_json_data('grund', kunde_id);
            }

            else
             {
                $('#grund').html('<option value="">Bitte wähle</option>');
        }
```

Beispiel der Json Datei:

"id": "35",
  "name": "Tranportschaden",
  "parent_id": "4"
},

Comment: You need to show your code for `load_json_data()` so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Emmanuel, I'll have to assume that `load_json_data` is an asynchronous call and returns a `promise` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

You'll have to wait for the promise to `resolve` and only after `read` the `data` its provided in the `response`. I'll have to assume the data structure here, but let's try to create something with those assumptions which I believe will help you understand and you going to be able to fix your problem.

I'll also use syntax to make this a bit easier to read (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), here it goes:

```
    $(document).on('change', '#kunde', async function () {
        var kunde_id = $(this).val();
        if (kunde_id != '')
         {
            var responseData = await load_json_data('grund', kunde_id);
            var count = responseData.value
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              $('#grund').html('<option value="">Bitte wähle</option>');
             }
        }

        else
         {
            $('#grund').html('<option value="">Bitte wähle</option>');
    }
```

You'll notice the use of `async` prefix before `function ()` and also the `await` keyword, if this syntax is unfamiliar to you, no worries! What's important is to understand the procedure, where you have to make a call and wait, and only after doing something with the response!

Use the first URL I've provided to do it without the syntax sugar in my example. Where you'll do something like:

```
load_json_data(...).then(...)
```

The three dots `...` is just a placeholder as you need to fulfil these yourself, just follow the documentation ;)

Notes: The `responseData.value` is just an example, I've assumed the data structure just to help you understand that you need to access your particular property. You may want to check the response body and look for the desired property, for example do console.log(responseData).